Polyhedra volume, faces and edges from vertices
Given a set of vertices in 3D corresponding to a convex polyhedron, what is the most efficient way to find its volume, faces, and edges?
I've found some techniques using convex hulls. But I think I might be wasting computations because I already know there are no internal points.

Don't know the usefulness to you, but Polymake at https://polymake.org/doku.php/start will do such computations.

@RichardStanley I need to impement some of methods in a custom code. Although I cannot use Polymake, its documentation lead me to useful papers.  Thank you.

Assumed that you look for convex polyhedra, then at least the volume bit is quite an "easy" derivation from the already pre-obtained faces: simply take any internal point as center (such as eg. the medium of the given vertices) and then consider the set of pyramids with the faces each for base and that center as its tip.
